# Is $\int (x-1)dx$ and $\int(x-1)d(x-1)$ same?

Tags: calculus, integration

Just confuse whether $$\int (x-1)\,dx\quad\text{and}\quad\int (x-1)\,d(x-1)$$ have same result? Many people tell me they are same (even math PhD), their reason is $dx=d(x-1)$, so answer must be same. But personally, I think the first one, answer is $x^2/2-x+C$, and second one is $(x-1)^2/2$. And I think the $\int(x-1)\,d(x-1)$ is to integral the area bases on $y$-axis. If I am wrong, tell me why and how I wrong?

Besides, any suggest when we deal with the situation such as $d\sin(x),\ de^x\ \text{and}\ d\ln(x)$.

Comment: The first is $1/2*x^2 - x$ "plus a constant" and the second is $1/2*(x - 1)^2 $ "plus a constant".  $1/2*(x-1)^2  = 1/2*x^2 - x + 1/2 $ So the first is $1/2*x^2 - x$ "plus a constant" and the second is $1/2*x^2 - x$" plus 1/2 and a constant".  As "plus a constant" and "plus 1/2 and a constant" are the same thing, they are both the same.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "Besides, any suggest when we deal with the situation such as..." What "situation" exactly? And what do you want to "deal with"? Do you mean, e.g., how do you write these differentials in the form $g(x) \,dx$?

Comment: What do you mean by "integral the area bases on y-axis"?

Comment: I'd say all of these $d(f(x))$ are abuse of notation (if you're dealing with the regular Riemann integral) and people use it for shorthand substitutions ($\frac d {dx} f(x)= f'(x)"\rightarrow" d(f(x))=f'(x)dx$).

Answer (score 7):

It might depend on what you mean by $d(x-1)$ in the integral.

You have 
$$
\int x - 1\; dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + c.
$$

Now the integral
$$
\int x-1\; d(x-1)
$$
is usually understood to be the integral
$$
\int u\; du
$$
where $u = x-1$. Here indeed $du = dx$ and so the integral is
$$
\int u\; du = \frac{1}{2}u^2 + d = \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + d = \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + \frac{1}{2} + d.
$$
You can "absorb" the $\frac{1}{2}$ into the constant, and so the integrals are indeed the same.

Comment: You right and make me really clear, but do you have any suggestion when we get some different differential , like d(sin(x)),d(e^x). Besides, I think the∫(x-1)d(x-1) is to integral the area bases on y-axis in terms of the geometrical meaning, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int (x-1)\ \text{d}x = \frac{x^2}{2} - x + C$$

$$\int (x-1)\ \text{d}(x-1) \equiv \int z\ \text{d}z = \frac{z^2}{2} + C = \frac{(x-1)^2}{2} + C$$

Back to $x$:

$$ = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2} - x + C = \frac{x^2}{2} - x + C'$$

Thence they are indeed the same modulo the constants C and C'.

Comment: Thank you, but any suggestion when we get some different differential , like d(sin(x)),d(e^x).

Comment: @zabbak Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral if you want a more rigorous approach.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that in asking the question you included a constant $C$ in your first integral, but omitted to do so in your second.  That constant — which ought to be in *both* expressions — is the clue to explaining why these two formulas are in fact equivalent.

I think it is important, first, to realize that when we write an indefinite integral like
$$\int {x-1} \space  dx=\frac{1}{2}x^2 -x + C$$
the right-hand-side denotes not a single function, but an entire family of functions that differ from one another only be a constant.  Put another way:  For any constant $C$, the function $\frac{1}{2}x^2 -x + C$ is **an** antiderivative of $x-1$.

Now consider your second integral.  You wrote:
$$\int {x-1} \space d(x-1)=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2$$
If you multiply out the right-hand side, you get $\frac{1}{2}(x^2-2x+1)=\frac{1}{2}x^2-x+\frac{1}{2}$.  Compare this with the result above it, and you see that it is exactly the same thing, with $C=\frac{1}{2}$.  So in fact $\frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2$ is a member of the family of functions denoted by $\frac{1}{2}x^2 -x + C$.

**ETA:**  Regarding other differentials:  It's not clear to me what exactly you are asking, but here are a few equivalences that might help:
$$d(e^x)=e^x\space dx$$
$$d(\sin x) = \cos x \space dx$$
$$d(\ln x) = \frac{1}{x} \space dx$$